# JS getting value from select option applying to object - undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, selected

I have HTML :

```
<select id="select">
        <option selected="selected" value="amon_amarth">Amon Amarth</option>
        <option value="arch_enemy">Arch Enemy</option>
        <option value="children_bodom">Children of_bodom</option>
        <option value="dark_tranquillity">Dark tranquillity</option>
        <option value="death">Death</option>
        <option value="ensiferum">Ensiferium</option>
        <option value="korpiklaani">Korpiklaani</option>
        <option value="norther">Norther</option>
        <option value="white_skull">White skull</option>
    </select>
    <button id="play">play</button>
```

Then I receive value from select option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function () {
    let value = $(this).val().toString();
    let clicksound  = ss_soundbits('sound/' + music.value);
    $('#play').click(function () {
      // ss_soundbits('sound/' + music.value).playclip();
      clicksound.playclip();
      console.log(music);
      console.log(value);
      console.log(music.value);
    });
  })
});
```

console.log(music) - is my object, it is ok:

```
Object { amon_amarth: "amon_amarth_the_pursuit_of_vikings_(NaitiMP3.ru).mp3", arch_enemy: "Arch_Enemy-09_Ravenous_(muzroom.online).mp3", children_bodom: "children_of_bodom_are_you_dead_yet_(NaitiMP3.ru).mp3", dark_tranquillity: "dark_tranquillity_-_haven_2000_-_dark_tranquillity_-_rundown_(zf.fm).mp3", death: "death_-_painkiller_gon_nad_dzhudas_prist_(zf.fm).mp3", ensiferum: "ensiferum-ahti_(mp3CC.com).mp3", korpiklaani: "korpiklaani-midsummer-night_(mp3CC.com).mp3", norther: "Norther - Last Breath (ouronlyhope.org).mp3", white_skull: "white-skull-high-treason_(mp3CC.com).mp3", siplyi: "white-skull-high-treason_(mp3CC.com).mp3", … }
```

console.log(music) - is my value, it is ok as well:    norther

But when I am trying to apply my value to Object (music.value) it says: undefined

Nevertheless it works if I put

```
<button onclick="clicksound.play()">
```

And have following code in my js file:

```
let clicksound = ss_soundbits('sound/' + music.amon_amarth);
```

What am I doing wrong? I spent all day to solve this problem. I can fix it with different buttons/div's but I still want to understand how can I fix current issue.
Thanks!

Comment: How about `console.log(value);`? You can not access to `value` variable in `$("select").on('change')`.

Comment: From your posted code, you are missing a **";"** in the penultimate line.

Comment: You declare `let value = $(this).val().toString();` but you never use the variable, but it looks to be exactly what you're trying to get. Try `let clicksound  = ss_soundbits('sound/' + value);` ?

Comment: `let value = $(this).val().toString();` just as a sidenote - `value` of form elements is always of type String in Javascript, no need to cast it.

Comment: You should be using `music[value]`. Using `music.value` will instead access a key called "value" in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this is the result you're trying to achieve:

*Btw, amazing musical taste :)*

```js
let music = {}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
    let value = $(this).val();
    music.value = value;
    // let clicksound  = ss_soundbits('sound/' + music.value);
    $('#play').click(function() {
      // ss_soundbits('sound/' + music.value).playclip();
      // clicksound.playclip();
      console.log(music);
      console.log(value);
      console.log(music.value);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option selected="selected" value="amon_amarth">Amon Amarth</option>
    <option value="arch_enemy">Arch Enemy</option>
    <option value="children_bodom">Children of_bodom</option>
    <option value="dark_tranquillity">Dark tranquillity</option>
    <option value="death">Death</option>
    <option value="ensiferum">Ensiferium</option>
    <option value="korpiklaani">Korpiklaani</option>
    <option value="norther">Norther</option>
    <option value="white_skull">White skull</option>
</select>
<button id="play">play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation of accessing values in an object is only when you are referring to the actual key itself. `music.value` means you want to retrieve the key-value pair whose key is literally called "value", which does not exist.

As per my comment, what you want is to use `music[value]` instead, where `value` is a variable that stores the reference you want.

On a side note, you should not be binding event handlers **within** event handlers: this causes the `click` event to be bound to the `#play` element **every time a `change` event is fired**, and this is extremely unperformant. See the refactored code below:

```
let clicksound;

$("select").on('change', function () {
    let value = $(this).val();
    clicksound  = ss_soundbits('sound/' + music[value]);
  });

$('#play').click(function () {
  clicksound.playclip();
});
```

Comment: Thats what I need. Thank you very much for explanation, my friend! Now everything is clear for me.